# C++ window image in loop causes lag

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to grab the image of a window to grab pixel data. The following snippet is run inside of a loop. It seems that everything is working fine, but after a few minutes of running the application starts to hang. My guess is that there is some sort of memory leak. I hope someone can point out what i am doing wrong here.

```
void ScreenShot(LPCSTR filename)
{
    RECT DesktopParams;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &DesktopParams);
    DWORD Width = DesktopParams.right - DesktopParams.left;
    DWORD Height = DesktopParams.bottom - DesktopParams.top;

    DWORD FileSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + (sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + 1 * (Width*Height * 4));
    char *BmpFileData = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, FileSize);

    PBITMAPFILEHEADER BFileHeader = (PBITMAPFILEHEADER)BmpFileData;
    PBITMAPINFOHEADER  BInfoHeader = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER)&BmpFileData[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];

    BFileHeader->bfType = 0x4D42; // BM
    BFileHeader->bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
    BFileHeader->bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    BInfoHeader->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    BInfoHeader->biPlanes = 1;
    BInfoHeader->biBitCount = 24;
    BInfoHeader->biCompression = BI_RGB;
    BInfoHeader->biHeight = Height;
    BInfoHeader->biWidth = Width;

    RGBTRIPLE *Image = (RGBTRIPLE*)&BmpFileData[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)];
    RGBTRIPLE color;

    HDC CaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(DevC);
    HBITMAP CaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(DevC, Width, Height);
    SelectObject(CaptureDC, CaptureBitmap);
    BitBlt(CaptureDC, 0, 0, Width, Height, DevC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
    GetDIBits(CaptureDC, CaptureBitmap, 0, Height, Image, (LPBITMAPINFO)BInfoHeader, DIB_RGB_COLORS);



    RGBTRIPLE *pixel = get_pixel(BInfoHeader, Image, 100, 100);
    cout << (int)pixel->rgbtRed << ", " << (int)pixel->rgbtBlue << "," << (int)pixel->rgbtGreen << endl;
    GlobalFree(BmpFileData);

}
```

After some more testing i realized that if i comment out get_pixel, the lage goes away.

```
RGBTRIPLE * get_pixel(PBITMAPINFOHEADER  BInfoHeader, RGBTRIPLE *Image, int x, int y)
{
    return &Image[(BInfoHeader->biHeight - 1 - y)*BInfoHeader->biWidth + x];
}
```

Comment: Did you open the task manager and see that your application constantly grows in size or did you just guess that there is a memory leak?

Comment: You're leaking `CaptureDC`, `CaptureBitmap`, and not restoring the `HBITMAP` returned by `SelectObject`. So yes, there is some sort of memory leak.

Comment: @o_weisman yes i watched my applications process grow in task manager.

Comment: @JonathanPotter your absolutely right, i think after fixing that my issue will be resolved!

Comment: You should zero the memory. Or just use `std::vector<BYTE> BmpFileData(FileSize)` instead of `GlobalAlloc`. Also 24-bit bitmap needs padding, unless you get luck and `width * 3` is divisible by 4. And file size calculation is wrong (it's too big)